# Trying to make navbar brand logo image responsive

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar, responsive-images

I googled everything by now and tried everything including `img-fluid`, did not work, I can't seem to figure out how to make the image responsive (pretty much a beginner lol), if I resize the browser window the image stays the same size, does not scale.

The logo image size that am trying to keep is 734px x 132px

Edit: I have already tried auto height and still doesn't work

```
.navbar-brand {
    color: $primary;
    padding: 0;

    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 132px;
        max-height: 132px;

        @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
            max-height: 132x;
        }
    }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    .header-navbar-top-right-search {
        margin-left: auto;
    }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
    .header-navbar-top-left {
        max-width: 42%;
        flex: 0 0 42%;
    }

    .header-navbar-top-center {
        max-width: 16%;
        flex: 0 0 16%;
    }

    .header-navbar-top-right-search {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
    }

    .header-navbar-top-right {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
    }
}

.header-top-line {
    background-color: $section-bg;

    a:not(.edit-link) {
        padding: 22px $spacer 20px;
        font-size: 0.8125rem;
        line-height: 1.125rem;
    }

    .login-list > .nav-item a {
        font-weight: 700;
    }
}

.header-bottom-line {
    background-color: $white;
}

.header-quantity-box {
    margin-left: $spacer * 0.25;
}

.nav-link,
.search-module .btn,
.header-navbar a {
    color: $white;

    &:active,
    &:hover {
        color: $primary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include all the navbar code?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late reply!

Comment: Can post your HTML also?

Answer (score 0):

Give it some width and put the height as auto.

```
img{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately did not work :-( thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

**Update 1**

Now see, You can update `max-width` as your need

*Snippet*

```css
.navbar-brand {
    color: blue;
    padding: 0;

}
.navbar-brand img {
   max-width: 734px;
   height: auto;
   width:30%;
   margin: auto;
} 
   
@media only screen and(max-width: 768px){
  .navbar-brand img{
    width: 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_160x56dp.png" title="borhykerteszetcsomagküldés" alt="borhykerteszetcsomagküldés"></a>
```

**Did this help you** ?

Comment: For some reason (that I know not) it resized the logo and it appears way smaller now, as if it was 50% smaller -  this is if the browser window is full screen, if i start resizing the browser window at one point the logo appears the original 734px x 132px size

I'm going to paste the html too:

Comment: <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img style="border: 0; max-width: 734px;" src="https://borhykerteszetcsomagkuldes.cdn.shoprenter.hu/custom/borhykerteszetcsomagkuldes/image/cache/w734h132m00/BorhyDEMOWEBSHOP/sandbox/borhylogo_transparent.png?v=1628260193" title="borhykerteszetcsomagküldés" alt="borhykerteszetcsomagküldés"></a>

Comment: Can u send a screen shot

Comment: Now run the snippet full-page and try resizing your browser

Comment: sending a screenshot:  https://ibb.co/9bJpYwm
the upper one is how the logo appears with the code snippet you sent, and the one below is the size i would like it to appear, thanks for trying to solve this problem!!